# how can i stream few messages and add more data when swipe up

Tags: firebase, flutter, chat

i am using firebase as backend
i am trying to create live chat app i can use stream.snapshot() but i want to read the newest 5 msg . and read more data when i swipe up . i can make it done with future and limit the query to 5 mesages and add more data to that query using startAfter(query)  how can i do it in stream
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIkKw.png)

`Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> messageStream(String? userEmail, String roomId) { return firebaseFirestore .collection(chatsCollection) .doc(roomId) .collection(messagesCollection) .orderBy(timeField, descending: true) .limit(5) .snapshots(); }`